# SharePoint 2013 - Getting SPSite.Url from SharePoint DB

Tags: database, spweb, spsite, spsitedataquery

I'm working directly against the SharePoint DB (I know it is highly not recommended but I need to, for several reasons).

I'm trying to get the `SPSite.Url` property ("`http://baseurl/sites/somename`") but can't figure out how to do that. I can only find and get the second part ("`sites/somename`") for each site.

Does any one know which stored procedures I need to use in order to get that?

Comment: Do you really need to get that directly from the db? Powershell can do that with ease.

Comment: Yes I do... but can you please show me how to do that with Powershell anyway?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of all site collection available in a farm or a webapplication?

Comment: @Christoffer yes

Comment: Sites in i a webapp: Get-spwebapplication -limit all | get-spsite -limit all

Comment: Or if you need to target a specific content db: get-spsite -limit all -contentdatabase WSS_Content_Something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that is: Retrieving the Farm Id--> Retrieving the Alternate URL Collection Ids--> Retrieving the Alternate URL Collections--> Alternate URL Matching

You can find in this link: [[MS-WSSFO3]: Windows SharePoint Services (WSS): File Operations Database Communications Version 3 Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh624619(v=office.12).aspx) documentation with detailed explanation under this section:

> Site Collection Lookup